# IntelliSense doesn't work in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

Can anyone help me figure out why IntelliSense doesn't work in VS 2008?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there is something wrong with your installation of Visual Studio - without more information the best thing we can recommend is reinstalling the IDE.

The only other thing I can think of is possibly intellisense has been disabled - try re-enabling it like this:

> 1. `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense`
> 2. Check the box that says "Show completion list..."